# New Install of Ubuntu only allows 4:3 aspect ratio

Tags: xorg, display, display-resolution, xrandr

Yesterday I upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04, but it failed to work with any of my graphics drivers. I dropped back down to 14.04 and am having issues with my screen resolution. The aspect ratio is stuck at 4:3. I go to system settings and click display, and the only option is 4:3. I followed tutorials allowing me to set different screen resolutions (using xrandr and cvt). However, this only got me to the point where the option to select the new resolution is in the "Display" menu. I now get a new error when I try to apply it.

This is the tutorial I followed:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LiP-YqtZoNQ

I followed it to approximately 3:13.

When I go into Display under System settings to change to the new resolution, I get this error in a popup window:

> required virtual size does not fit available size: requested=(1280, 720), >minimum=(1152, 864), maximum=(1152, 864)

The solution to this problem should be able to be solved by adding an "xorg.conf" file to /etc/X11/ with a few extra lines added. I ran

> sudo X -configure

to generate the default xorg.conf file.

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "X.org Configured"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
EndSection

Section "Files"
    ModulePath   "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi"
    FontPath     "built-ins"
EndSection

Section "Module"
    Load  "glx"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier  "Keyboard0"
    Driver      "kbd"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier  "Mouse0"
    Driver      "mouse"
    Option      "Protocol" "auto"
    Option      "Device" "/dev/input/mice"
    Option      "ZAxisMapping" "4 5 6 7"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "Monitor0"
    VendorName   "Monitor Vendor"
    ModelName    "Monitor Model"
EndSection

Section "Device"
        ### Available Driver options are:-
        ### Values: <i>: integer, <f>: float, <bool>: "True"/"False",
        ### <string>: "String", <freq>: "<f> Hz/kHz/MHz",
        ### <percent>: "<f>%"
        ### [arg]: arg optional
        #Option     "Accel"                 # [<bool>]
        #Option     "SWcursor"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "EnablePageFlip"        # [<bool>]
        #Option     "ColorTiling"           # [<bool>]
        #Option     "ColorTiling2D"         # [<bool>]
        #Option     "RenderAccel"           # [<bool>]
        #Option     "SubPixelOrder"         # [<str>]
        #Option     "AccelMethod"           # <str>
        #Option     "ShadowPrimary"         # [<bool>]
        #Option     "EXAVSync"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "EXAPixmaps"            # [<bool>]
        #Option     "ZaphodHeads"           # <str>
        #Option     "SwapbuffersWait"       # [<bool>]
        #Option     "DeleteUnusedDP12Displays"  # [<bool>]
        #Option     "DRI3"                  # [<bool>]
        #Option     "DRI"                   # <i>
        #Option     "TearFree"              # [<bool>]
    Identifier  "Card0"
    Driver      "radeon"
    BusID       "PCI:0:1:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen0"
    Device     "Card0"
    Monitor    "Monitor0"
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     1
        Virtual 1280 720
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     4
        Virtual 1280 720
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     8
        Virtual 1280 720
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     15
        Virtual 1280 720
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     16
        Virtual 1280 720
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
        Virtual 1280 720
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

I added in the "Virtual 1280 720" line in the screen section (as seen by the snippet of the file generated). I copied this into /etc/X11/ as xorg.conf, and it crashes X11 every time I boot.

I am really at a loss for why this problem is now happening. I have never had an issue like this before. It is very frustrating.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: To properly paste multiline fixed-width text, paste it, select it with the mouse, and press the `{}` button in the editor toolbar. For inline fixed-width text, surround it with backticks (`\``).